# Keep styles of an 'exported to pdf' html table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jspdf, export-to-pdf

On my MVC project I have the following html table:

```
<div id="tableToPrint">
    <table border="0" id="tbl" cellspacing="25">
        <tr class="te">
            <th align="left">DATE</th>
            <th align="left">METHOD</th>
            <th align="left">DEPOSIT</th>
            <th align="left">WITHDRAWAL</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: accountInfo -->
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><span data-bind="text: moment(new Date(orderDate())).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span></td>
            <td valign="top"><span data-bind="text: type"></span> </td>
            <td class="deposit" valign="top"><span data-bind="text: $root.formatCurrency(deposit())" id="deposit"></span></td>
            <td valign="top"><span data-bind="text: $root.formatCurrency(withdrawal())"></span> </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <tr class="last">
            <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top"><span data-bind="text:  $root.totalDeposit()"></span></td>
            <td valign="top"><span data-bind="text:  $root.totalWithdrawal()"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have a button 'Export to PDF' that works properly but **loses the design**, it gets exported witout all the styles.

This is mt javascript code that exports the table to pdf using the jspdf library:

```
 self.exportToPdf = function () {
    var newPdf = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#tableToPrint': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    // newPdf.setFontSize(16);
    var html = $("#tableToPrint").html();
    var margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    newPdf.fromHTML(
        html, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
    newPdf.save("YourTable.pdf");
}
```

Is there anyway to keep the original design of the table in the exported pdf?
Or at least to design it through the javascript code that export the table to pdf?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what settings has to be done to your `JsPdf` plugin because I dont see any documentation of it. But obvious reasons with few plugins out there is they require all the `styles to be given inline` rather than class. Some plugin's take a snapshot of the screen and makes it a PDF which will not have issue with stylings

Comment: @user3378165 Have the same problem. Could you tell me plz, as I  understand from the answer below there is no way to export design of html table automatically? Without js style settings. For example if I don't know exactly what design will be in html table but I want to export it into pdf?

Comment: @RoGGeR I wasn't able to figure out how to export the table with the original design, had to design it by my own.

Comment: @user3378165 ok, thanks for your answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solved my issue:

```
self.exportToPdf = function () {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('#tableToPrint')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },
     function (dispose) {
         // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
         //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
         pdf.save('YourTable.pdf');
     }, margins
    );
}
```